# Why 'setup.py develop' allow to import directories without '__init__.py'?

Tags: python, setuptools

I'm working on simple project looking like this:

```
\setup.py
\abcd
\abcd\__init__.py
\abcd\history\docs.py
```

When I run `setup.py develop`, against my venv, `import abcd.history` works. when I run `setup.py install`, against my venv, `import abcd.history` returns me an exception:

```
ImportError: No module named 'abcd.history'
```

Why? Python version is 3.5.1

Answer (score 2):

`setup.py develop` installs your package as [sort of a pseudo-symlink](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#development-mode) to your development directory, so stuff like `\abcd\history\` is visible there. `import abcd.history` then imports the folder as an [implicit namespace package](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/), a feature introduced in Python 3.3. Implicit namespace packages don't require `__init__.py`.

`setup.py install` doesn't create the pseudo-symlink. It only installs what it's configured to install, and apparently, it wasn't configured to install `abcd.history`.

Comment: `setup.py install` indeed does not copy `abcd\history` directory into venv.
Egg file inside venv contains only `\abcd\__init__.py`

Answer (score 0):

```
$ ls -R1
sub
test-sub.py

./sub:
__init__.py
module

./sub/module:
testxxx.py

$ cat test-sub.py 
#! /usr/bin/env python
import sub.module

$ python3.5 test-sub.py 
$ python3.4 test-sub.py 
$ python2.7 test-sub.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test-sub.py", line 3, in <module>
    import sub.module
ImportError: No module named module
```

Resume: Python 3 can import a submodule without `__init__.py` (only the top-level directory of a module requires `__init__.py`), Python 2 cannot. Try to find out where Python 2 has creeped and crippled your installation.

Answer (score -1):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages):

> The __init__.py files are required to make Python treat the directories as containing packages; this is done to prevent directories with a common name, such as string, from unintentionally hiding valid modules that occur later on the module search path.

There must be something about the fact that `setup.py develop` just points your interpreter to the local directory that allows for the import of `abcd.history` that fails when you try to actually `install` it into an environment.